# Displaying SQL results with an condition DGV VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, filter

My problem consist in show values into a cell of a DGV control, for example:

MySQL Table:

```
ID - Name      - Price    - Type
1    Mouse Pad   2.85$    -  a
2    Keyboard    10.50$   -  a
3    Hard Disk   80.00$   -  c
4    Web Cam     15.02$   -  b
5    Printer     45.62$   -  c
6    DVD Writer  20.00$   -  b
```

My DataGridView Control:

```
ID - Name       - PriceA    - PriceB    - PriceC
```

I want display the results Filtering with these conditions [VB.NET sintax]:

```
If SQLcolumn(Type) = a Then, show the price into PriceA into the DGV.
If SQLcolumn(Type) = b Then, show the price into PriceB into the DGV.
If SQLcolumn(Type) = c Then, show the price into PriceC into the DGV.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a custom List with 5 columns : ID,Name,PriceA,PriceB,PriceC
and after getting data from database and filling the data into a datatable  for example , you can proccess the datatable row by row and check if the Type column of your datatablerow is Type 'a' then add the row into the List and add the Price to the PriceA column of the list and after proccessing the whole datatable and adding all it's rows to the List , you can set the List as Datagridview datasource !

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the SQL Pivot operator:

```
SELECT  ID ,
        Name ,
        [a] AS [TypeA] ,
        [b] AS [TypeB] ,
        [c] AS [TypeC]
FROM    tbl PIVOT ( SUM(Price) FOR TYPE IN ( a, b, c ) ) AS pvt
```